# Getting remote Event-log using .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, event-log

How can I get remote eventlog using .netcore?
also, can I get it from different domains? (using creds)

should I use 
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog from Nuget?

Include the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog on the program.cs file

Any example of how to do this will be a great help

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want and want to achieve? Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Also, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The said package does not provide capabilities to read the event log - not from the local, nor from a remote machine - but only to write entries (as just this is need for logging purposes). If you need to read entries, you need to use [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.EventLog). An example doing that would look much like it does for the .NET full framework (search SO or google for it).